# An entity with a oneToMany relationship with one table and one ManyToMany relationshp with another table returns duplicate records when rtrieved by ID

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I have an Entity class as below, which has 1 oneToMany mapping and 1 manyToMany mapping:

```
    class Parent {
       
       @Id
       String id;
       
       @Column
       String name;

       @OneToMany
       List<Address> addresses;

       @ManyToMany
       Set<Child> children;
}
```

I'm aware about creating Foreign key references in the 'oneToMany' relationship, and using a Join table for the 'manyToMany' relationship.

Let's say I have the below data:

```
Parent table:
_______________
P_id      Name
p1        John


Address table:
_________________________________
A_id      Address      Fk_p_id
a1        London        p1
a2       Amsterdam.     p2


Child table
C_id        Name
c1         child1
c2         child2


Person_Child_Mapping table
p_id   c_id
p1       c1
p2      c2
p3      c3
```

Now, when I do a get Parent by ID, hibernate returns back a Parent object with 2 'Addresses', but has 6 'Child' objects, where each Child object is duplicated. Is there a reason why that might be happening?

Comment: Since JPA manages uniqness of java objects having the same `@Id, it is surprising that the collection of chidren contains duplicated objects with the same `@Id`. Could you show your query ?

Comment: Is your table description accurate and that you only have one Address and one Child associated to one parent? I'd expect this might be if there were more than one result, like if you had two addresses for the one parent being fetched, and that  Hibernate  isn't able to handle the cartesian joins going on with the *ToMany relationships. 1 parent, N addresses and M children means 1*N*M rows returned for the parent, which if not done right, would result in N duplicates of Children (and possibly M duplicates of Addresses).

Comment: If so, and Hibernate cannot handle multiple *ToMany relationships eagerly; you would want to help it out anyway by making one or more lazily fetched. Other providers also give mechanisms (or just don't default to always joining relationships) to specify fetching relationships in a separate query, even if eager, which would prevent this problem - I think the only thing I know of Hibernate having is the BatchSize annotation which would help but doesn't allow a lot of options.

Comment: @Chris , yes I think that is what is happening, it is returning back 1*N*M. I'm fetching both the relationships using 'Eager' fetching mechanism. Do you recommend I do an 'Lazy' fetch to reduce the number of joins hibernate is performing?

Comment: If I knew you'd be still always be fetching those ManyToMany references, I'd go with a batchFetch operation ( https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_batchfetch.htm ). I believe the hibernate batchSize annotation is similar to BatchFetchType=IN, but with a limit to the number of entities IDs included in batch fetch query. Lazy vs eager depends on your application itself, though if you rarely need to fetch that relationship, and when fetch a list of parents may only need to get the children from one, don't use eager, and maybe not even batching